# Can I use costmap_2d as a standalone node, without using the navigation stack?

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-melodic, 2dcostmap, costmap-2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I have some point cloud data and would like to construct a costmap for navigation purposes. I couldn't find any tutorial on costmaps specifically, most tutorials are often about using costmap with the navigation stack. Here is my attempt to run the costmap node as a standalone node.

My `.yaml` file

```
global_frame: map
robot_base_frame: zed_camera_center
transform_tolerance: 0.2
robot_radius: 0.6

update_frequency: 5.0
publish_frequency: 2.0
rolling_window: true
static_map: false

width: 100
height: 100
resolution: 0.05

obstacle_range: 5.5
raytrace_range: 8.0

footprint: [[ 0.6096,  1.1684], [-0.6096,  1.1684], [-0.6096, -1.1684], [ 0.6096, -1.1684]]
footprint_padding: 0.10

observation_sources: point_cloud_sensor

point_cloud_sensor: {sensor_frame: zed_camera_center, data_type: PointCloud2, topic: 
/zed/point_cloud/cloud_registered, marking: true, clearing: true}
```

And here is my launch file.

```
<node name="costmap_node" pkg="costmap_2d" type="costmap_2d_node" >
    <rosparam file="$(find path_planning)/params/costmap_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
</node>
```

Here is the terminal output when I run the launch file

```
neil@neil:~/Workspace/self-driving-golf-cart/ros$ roslaunch path_planning navigation.launch 
... logging to /home/neil/.ros/log/2e1eac9e-5744-11e9-8f6a-bcec23c374bf/roslaunch-neil-15292.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://neil:33545/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /costmap_node/local_costmap/footprint: [[0.6096, 1.1684]...
 * /costmap_node/local_costmap/footprint_padding: 0.1
 * /costmap_node/local_costmap/global_frame: map
 * /costmap_node/local_costmap/height: 100
 * /costmap_node/local_costmap/observation_sources: point_cloud_sensor
 * /costmap_node/local_costmap/obstacle_range: 5.5
 * /costmap_node/local_costmap/point_cloud_sensor/clearing: True
 * /costmap_node/local_costmap/point_cloud_sensor/data_type: PointCloud2
 * /costmap_node/local_costmap/point_cloud_sensor/marking: True
 * /costmap_node/local_costmap/point_cloud_sensor/sensor_frame: zed_camera_center
 * /costmap_node/local_costmap/point_cloud_sensor/topic: /zed/point_cloud/...
 * /costmap_node/local_costmap/publish_frequency: 2.0
 * /costmap_node/local_costmap/raytrace_range: 8.0
 * /costmap_node/local_costmap/resolution: 0.05
 * /costmap_node/local_costmap/robot_base_frame: zed_camera_center
 * /costmap_node/local_costmap/robot_radius: 0.6
 * /costmap_node/local_costmap/rolling_window: True
 * /costmap_node/local_costmap/static_map: False
 * /costmap_node/local_costmap/transform_tolerance: 0.2
 * /costmap_node/local_costmap/update_frequency: 5.0
 * /costmap_node/local_costmap/width: 100
 * /rosdistro: melodic
 * /rosversion: 1.14.3

NODES
  /
    costmap_node (costmap_2d/costmap_2d_node)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [15303]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 2e1eac9e-5744-11e9-8f6a-bcec23c374bf
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [15317]
started core service [/rosout]
process[costmap_node-2]: started with pid [15324]
```

When I run `rostopic list`, none of the costmap topics shows up. I am wondering what I am doing wrong. Thank you very much! Sorry that I am very new to navigation with ROS.

Cheers,

Neil

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/320355/can-i-use-costmap_2d-as-a-standalone-node,-without-using-the-navigation-stack?/) by [NNie2019](https://answers.ros.org/users/40728/nnie2019/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2019-04-04

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) on 2019-04-04**:
"static_map: false"

Also, can you add output from terminal.

**Comment by [NNie2019](https://answers.ros.org/users/40728/nnie2019/) on 2019-04-04**:
I added that line to the yaml file. Unfortunately, it didn't work. Nothing changed. I added the terminal output. ROS didn't throw me any warnings or errors.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-04-04**:\

> I tried adding that to the yaml file. Unfortunately, it didn't work.

What do you mean? You couldn't copy and paste it?

**Comment by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) on 2019-04-04**:
"When I run rostopic list, none of the costmap topics show up".
What's the output you get for `rosnode info costmap_node` ?

**Comment by [NNie2019](https://answers.ros.org/users/40728/nnie2019/) on 2019-04-05**:
This is the output when I ran `rosnode info costmap_node`

```
Node [/costmap_node]
Publications: 
 * /rosout [rosgraph_msgs/Log]

Subscriptions: 
 * /tf [tf2_msgs/TFMessage]
 * /tf_static [tf2_msgs/TFMessage]

Services: 
 * /costmap_node/get_loggers
 * /costmap_node/set_logger_level


contacting node http://neil:43633/ ...
Pid: 24123
Connections:
 * topic: /rosout
    * to: /rosout
    * direction: outbound
    * transport: TCPROS
 * topic: /tf
    * to: /play_1554464258893539779 (http://neil:38919/)
    * direction: inbound
    * transport: TCPROS
 * topic: /tf_static
    * to: /play_1554464258893539779 (http://neil:38919/)
    * direction: inbound
    * transport: TCPROS
```

**Comment by [sgarciav](https://answers.ros.org/users/72940/sgarciav/) on 2021-04-05**:
Hello @NNie2019: Were you able to figure out how to run the `costmap_2d` node standalone? Executing `$ rosnode info costmap_node` yields the same for me as for you - i.e., no costmap topics being published.

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2021-04-07**:
You are not publishing the transform between  the `global_frame` and `robot_base_frame`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@NNie2019:

I know you asked your question back in 2019, but I recently ran into the same problem and may have an answer for those who might run into it as well.

First, your launch file is correct for loading the `costmap_2d` node in standalone mode. I'd recommend you make sure that the messages are printed to the terminal for easier debugging by adding the  `... output="screen" />` tag in the node call.

Now, since you're not specifying any [plugins in your params yaml file](https://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d/Tutorials/Configuring%20Layered%20Costmaps#Step_3:_Plugins_Specification), you should see a message printed out to your terminal stating that no plugins were specified and that some pre-Hydro parameters will be loaded. Something similar to this:

```
[ WARN] [1617798485.487554072, 1613598132.219868821]: costmap: Parameter "plugins" not provided, loading pre-Hydro parameters

[ INFO] [1617798485.493183425, 1613598132.219868821]: costmap: Using plugin "obstacle_layer"

[ INFO] [1617798485.515048394, 1613598132.240097096]:     Subscribed to Topics: 

[ INFO] [1617798485.523665166, 1613598132.250172045]: costmap: Using plugin "inflation_layer"
```

Since you're not seeing this message, it probably means that the node is waiting for the tf transform between your global frame and your robot base frame - `map` and `zed_camera_center`, respectively according to your parameter yaml file.

Make sure that the `\tf` topic is being published with this transform and you should see the costmap node start doing things. Namely, the first thing you should see is that plugin message like I mentioned above.

If it turns out that you're having a different issue, I recommend that you build the [navigation stack from source](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation) and add print statements to the costmap node files to see where it might be failing you.

Good luck!

---

Originally posted by [sgarciav](https://answers.ros.org/users/72940/sgarciav/) with karma: 26 on 2021-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1